# Good book on Bolza problem and Hamilton systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

I am working with problems that characterize the solutions with the Bolza problem and Hamiltonian systems. I think this belongs to the area of Optimal Control and calculus of variations. Need a good resource to learn about these topics.  Any suggestions?

A reference for the Bolza Problem: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Bolza_problem

Hamiltonian Systems: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Hamiltonian_system

Comment: Please, give www references to "Bolza problem". Personnaly, I had never heard of this name.

Comment: I added link for reference to Bolza problems.

Answer (score 0):

I found a book that seems pretty good. Will confirm quality once I use it a little.

"The Calculus of Variations" - Bruce van Brunt

Also recommended "Stochastic Differential Equations: An Introduction with Applications" - Bernt Oksendal